# Typescript + webpack outputs empty object

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to export a umd module w. webpack, and consume it via `<script>` tag.
my `tsconfig.json` is configured to export a `commonjs` file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true
 }
}
```

And my webpack config is set to output a umd lib,

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
      test: './src/index.tsx'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'test.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: "test",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "test",
      minify: false,
      
  })],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    open: true
  }
};
```

and my `src/index.ts` file

```
export function sayHi() {
  console.log('Hello')
}
```

when running `webpack serve` I see that my file was compiled and imported correctly to my HTML, but he trying to access `test` inside the js (chrome console) my lib is resolved to an empty object

```
{}
```

I'm expecting `test.sayHi()` to log the message, instead I get an error
`sayHi() is not a function`

What am I missing?
tried converting the TS module to umd others but none seem to work...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack compiles self invoke functions only, not the any other function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548707/webpack-compiles-self-invoke-functions-only-not-the-any-other-function)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert yes, there was an open issue on webpack-dev-server on that, I'm currently afk, I'll post it here when I'll be back

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert check out https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2484