# Webpack compiles self invoke functions only, not the any other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-5

I'm using Webpack to compile and bundle all my .js files into one. It compiles the imported jquery and bootstrap files, but when it comes to my own code in main.js as shown below it only compiles `console.log('Hello World');` but not the `searchTable` or any other function.

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import bootstrap from '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';

console.log('Hello World');

const searchTable = (tableId) => {
    const input = document.querySelector('#tableSearchInput');
    const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    const table = document.querySelector('#' + tableId);
    const tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        const td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
        if (td) {
            const txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './public/src/js/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/dist/js'),
        publicPath: '',
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    mode: 'production'
};
```

I searched a lot, but couldn't find an answer for this.
Your help may save me and I will be thankful!

Comment: You're not using `searchTable` nor export it. Webpack has a tree-shaking process that removes unused code

Comment: @GuerricP Thank you so much, your comment helped me and yes it was the case. Now it does work after invoking the function inside the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack has a process called Tree shaking. Tree shaking or dead code elimination means that unused modules will not be included in the bundle during the build process.
 Tools like webpack will detect dead code and mark it as “unused module” but it won’t remove the code.

To know more you can check this link: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/